# BadMethodCallException thrown by laravel dusk macro

Tags: php, laravel-dusk

I've defined the following macro in the `app/Providers/DuskServiceProvider` file but dusk is throwing a BadMethodCallException:

```
Browser::macro('logoutOfWave', function () {
        $this->visit(env('DUSK_URL'))
            ->script("localStorage.clear()");
        $this->visit(env('DUSK_URL'));

        return $this;
});
```

I'm using it in a dusk test:

```
public function testUnauthedUserIsRedirectedToLogin()
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $browser->logoutOfWave()->visit(env('DUSK_URL') . '/systems/create')->assertPathIs('/login');
    });
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
1) Tests\Browser\AddSystemsTest::testUnauthedUserIsRedirectedToLogin
BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method [logoutOfWave].

/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Browser.php:484
/var/www/html/tests/Browser/AddSystemsTest.php:20
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:67
/var/www/html/tests/Browser/AddSystemsTest.php:21
```

I have added the service provider to the `config/app.php` file to register it. I'm not sure why it can't find the macro?

Comment: Have you tested whether the service provider gets called? What's the result of `dd(Browser::hasMacro('logoutOfWave'));`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir The response is false. I have created the macros in a dusk service provider and included the dusk service provider in my config/app.php file. I'm not sure why the macro isn't loading

Comment: Put `dd('Provider is called.');` in the service provider. What happens when you run Dusk?

Comment: The message is shown in the console

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a fresh installation of Laravel?

Comment: We are using laradock so I could create a fresh install. Why do you think this would help?

Comment: Your code works for me, so something in your application must be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see the service providers were not being loaded when running tests. I've moved the browser macros into the `DuskTestCase.php` file and now it is running